How to Resolve Verify Traffic Error When Scraping Data from Shopee?
I'm currently working on a project where I need to scrape product data from Shopee. I'm using Python with the requests and BeautifulSoup libraries. However, I keep encountering a Verify Traffic error when trying to access certain pages.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I bypass this verification or handle this error effectively?

wheres your code?

I recently made a request, and my account has been blocked, so I’m unable to provide the specific code at the moment. However, I was using the requests and BeautifulSoup libraries to scrape product data from Shopee, and I kept encountering the "Verify Traffic" error.

We it's difficult to debug your code with the code. Secondly, there is api with documentation here. Why not use the open api?

Sorry, I currently do not have the required business legality documents for registration
